# I am trying to make a docs question answering program with AzureOpenAI and Langchain

Tags: azure, openai-api, langchain, large-language-model, azure-openai

```
llm = AzureOpenAI(openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY, deployment_name=OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_NAME, model_name=MODEL_NAME)



# Configure the location of the PDF file.
pdfReader = PdfReader('data\borders.pdf')


# Extract the text from the PDF file.
raw_text = ''
for i, page in enumerate(pdfReader.pages):
    text = page.extract_text()
    if text:
        raw_text += text

# Show first 1000 characters of the text.
raw_text[:1000]


# Split the text into chunks of 1000 characters with 200 characters overlap.
text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(        
    separator = "\n",
    chunk_size = 1000,
    chunk_overlap  = 200,
    length_function = len,
)
pdfTexts = text_splitter.split_text(raw_text)


# Show how many chunks of text are generated.
len(pdfTexts)

# Pass the text chunks to the Embedding Model from Azure OpenAI API to generate embeddings.
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY, deployment=OPENAI_EMBEDDING_MODEL_NAME, client="azure", chunk_size=1)

# Use FAISS to index the embeddings. This will allow us to perform a similarity search on the texts using the embeddings.
# https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/indexes/vectorstores/examples/faiss.html
pdfDocSearch = FAISS.from_texts(pdfTexts, embeddings)

# Create a Question Answering chain using the embeddings and the similarity search.
# https://docs.langchain.com/docs/components/chains/index_related_chains
chain = load_qa_chain(llm, chain_type="stuff")


# Perform first sample of question answering.
inquiry = "Who is the author of this book?"
docs = pdfDocSearch.similarity_search(inquiry)
chain.run(input_documents=docs, question=inquiry)
```

It gives this error:
openai.error.InvalidRequestError: The completion operation does not work with the specified model, gpt-4. Please choose different model and try again. You can learn more about which models can be used with each operation here: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2197993.

Comment: can you update your question with your deployment specification from azure open ai and other details that can help in reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

> It gives this error: openai.error.InvalidRequestError: The completion
> operation does not work with the specified model, gpt-4. Please choose
> a different model and try again. You can learn more about which models
> can be used with each operation here.

The above error occurs when you pass the wrong model or incorrect deployment in the configuration.

According to this **[Document-1](https://dev.to/bezbos/openai-completions-api-complete-guide-4ili)** and **[Document-2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/tutorials/embeddings?tabs=command-line#import-libraries-and-list-models)**   you need
**`text-davinci-003`** model for completion and **`text-embedding-ada-002`** model for embedding.

When I tried with the above model the code executed and gave me output.

**Code:**

```
from langchain.llms import AzureOpenAI
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores.faiss import FAISS
from langchain.chains.question_answering import load_qa_chain

OPENAI_API_KEY="xxxxx"
OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_NAME="testxxxa"    #deployment name with text-embedding-ada-002 model
deployment="textxxx"     #deployment name with text-davinci-003 model
openai_api_base1="xxxxxx"

llm = AzureOpenAI(openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY, deployment_name=deployment,openai_api_base=openai_api_base1,openai_api_version="2022-12-01",openai_api_type="azure")

pdfReader = PdfReader('example.pdf')

raw_text = ''
for i, page in enumerate(pdfReader.pages):
    text = page.extract_text()
    if text:
        raw_text += text

raw_text[:1000]

text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(        
    separator = "\n",
    chunk_size = 1000,
    chunk_overlap  = 200,
    length_function = len,
)
pdfTexts = text_splitter.split_text(raw_text)

len(pdfTexts)

embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY, deployment=OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_NAME, openai_api_base=openai_api_base1, openai_api_type="azure", openai_api_version="2022-12-01",chunk_size=1)

pdfDocSearch = FAISS.from_texts(pdfTexts, embeddings)
chain = load_qa_chain(llm, chain_type="stuff")
inquiry = "Which month is specified?"
docs = pdfDocSearch.similarity_search(inquiry)
print(chain.run(input_documents=docs, question=inquiry))
```

**Output:**

```
 September
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In OpenAI, you have to main operations regarding text generation:

- `completion`
- `chatCompletion`

Some models can be used for completion (eg: GPT3.5 version 0301, GPT-4, etc.), other can be used for chatCompletion (eg: GPT3.5 version 0613, GPT-4, etc.).

There is something that is not visible in your code which is the fact that langchain will use OpenAI with a `completion` operation within its step `load_qa_chain`.

Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/concepts/models#model-summary-table-and-region-availability
[image: GPT4 Details]

[image: GPT 3.5 details]

So in your case, you should pass a deployment which is compliant with a `completion` query when you set your `llm`:

```
llm = AzureOpenAI(openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY, deployment_name=OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_NAME, model_name=MODEL_NAME)
```